# ML; composite function n times

Tags: sml, ml

How is it possible to composite function f n times in ML?

composite two times;f(fx)
composite three times;f(f(fx)))
composite n times;   f(f(f(f.....(fx)))))))

I have tried;

```
fun composite f g =
          let h x = f(g x)
            in h end;

fun repeat f n =
       if n = 0 then x 
       else composite f repeat(f (n - 1));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

When you write recursive functions, divide your problem into general, recursive cases, and base cases that don't require recursion. For example, composing a function with itself *n* times sounds like the base case might be either when *n = 0* or when *n = 1* (either could work; I'll get back to that).

I'd encourage pattern matching, but when recursing integers, *if-then-else* do seem just as simple. In any case, all the examples have been written in both styles. A simple skeleton might be:

```
fun repeat f n =
    if n = 0
    then ?
    else ?

fun repeat f 0 = ?
  | repeat f 1 = ?
  | repeat f n = ?
```

#### On functions that return functions

I imagine some of the difficulty here is that `repeat` must return a function. Syntactically you can achieve that in various ways. Like John suggests, you might write it by extending `repeat` with `x`:

```
fun repeat f n x =
    if n = 1
    then f x
    else ...

fun repeat f 1 x = f x
  | repeat f n x = ...
```

to which the natural, but slightly weird, interpretation is "*`repeat` is a function that takes three arguments; the function `f`, the number of times it must be applied `n`, and `f`'s argument `x`* (?!)".

Alternatively, one might also write it like

```
fun repeat f n =
    if n = 1
    then (fn x => f x)
    else ...

fun repeat f 1 = (fn x => f x)
  | repeat f n = ...
```

which might be interpreted like "*`repeat` is a function that takes two arguments; the function `f` and the number of times it must be applied `n`, and returns a function that applies `f` to its argument `n` times.*"

Those definitions are really equivalent. You'll see that by translating the description into types:

- `val repeat : ('a -> 'a) -> int -> 'a -> 'a`
- `val repeat : ('a -> 'a) -> int -> ('a -> 'a)`

That last parenthesis is implied in the first type signature.

Sometimes it helps to think of functions with many *curried* arguments as "functions with many arguments", and other times it helps to think of them as "functions that return functions that take yet other arguments". And `repeat` seems to be a mixture of this; `n` is best thought of as "a second argument", but `x` is best thought of as "the argument that the function we're returning takes".

With this preference, and a preference for pattern matching, my recommended basis would be:

```
fun repeat f 0 = ...
  | repeat f 1 = f
  | repeat f n = ...
```

since `(fn x => f x)` and `f` are really one and the same function.

#### On the base case and the recursive case

You write:

> ```
> fun repeat f n =
>     if n = 0 then x 
>     else composite f repeat(f (n - 1));
> ```

1. The `x` in `then x` has the wrong type, since `repeat f n` must return a function. See above.
2. The case when applying `f` zero times is a little tricky. Whatever the result is, it should be the case that `repeat f 0` should give the same result regardless of `f`. Or put differently, that `f` isn't applied, although the `repeat f 0` does need to return *something*.
3. On the recursive case, really, you're just messing up the parentheses. John revealed the `o` operator that is Standard ML's built-in version of `composite` which I'll prefer, too:

   ```
   composite f (repeat f (n-1))
   f o repeat f (n-1)
   ```

   What you need to know about parentheses in Standard ML: You add them mostly to group things. When you write `composite f repeat (f (n-1))`, what you're saying is: "*`composite` is a three-argument function that takes `f`, `repeat` and `f (n-1)` as an argument*" and "*`f` is a function that takes integers as arguments*."

   When what you really wanted to say was "*`composite` takes `f` and the result of composing `f` with itself `n`–1 times, and composes those.*" It's a classic mistake when you come from languages that expect function calls to look like *`foo(arg1, arg, arg3)`* and one thinks this translates into *`foo(arg1 arg arg3)`* when in fact you wanted *`foo arg1 arg2 arg3`*. In Standard ML, this parenthesis forces *`arg1`* to be treated as a function and applies it to *`arg2`* and *`arg3`*, and applies *`foo`* to the result of that. Whoops!

Comment: I like how detailed some of your answers are. They give a lot of information for students to think about.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a problem with n = 0 branch but now it it is clear what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your ideas are close to being correct. You could use currying to make them work:

```
fun composite f g x = f(g(x));
```

SML infers its type as:

```
val composite = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b
```

which is exactly right for composition. Function application is left-associative, so

```
composite f g x
```

parses as

```
(composite f g) x
```

the function definition thus reads as giving the meaning of applying the function `(composite f g)` to an argument `x`. The meaning is, of course, to return the value `f(g(x))`.

You can test it:

```
fun square x = x*x
fun increment x = x + 1
val h = composite increment square
```

Then e.g. `h 5` evaluates to `26` as expected.

A similar tweak works for your second definition. It could begin:

```
fun repeat f n x =
```

since this seems like homework, I'll leave the details to you, but your current attempt is rather close to a correct solution.

Having said all this, you should know that composition is a built-in operator in SML, denoted by the lowercase `o`, and that `(op o)` could be used in your second definition in place of `composite`.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand how parentheses should be used.